Question about commutants of abelian C*-algebras
Let $\pi \colon A \to B(H)$ is a representation of abelian $C^{\ast}$-algebra with cyclic and separating vector $\Omega$. Is $\pi(A)'\subseteq B(H)$ abelian von Neumann algebra? If not what is a counter example? By GNS, of course $\pi \cong \pi_{\mu}$ for some measure $\mu$. Clearly $\pi_{\mu}(C(X))'$ is abelian. What about $\pi
(C(X))'$?

I’m not sure what your edited question is supposed to mean. If $\pi \cong \pi_\mu$ then of course $\pi(C(X))’ \cong \pi_\mu(C(X))’$.

You don’t even need $\Omega$ being separating. Indeed, write $A = C_0(K)$ where $K$ is the spectrum of $A$. $\langle \pi(\cdot) \Omega, \Omega\rangle$ is then a positive linear functional on $A$, so it induces a finite Radon measure $\mu$ on $K$. As $\Omega$ is cyclic, $\pi$ is just the GNS representation associated to $\mu$, i.e., the representation is simply the natural representation of $C_0(K)$ on $L^2(K, \mu)$. It is now a standard exercise to show that the commutatant of $C_0(K)$ in $B(L^2(K, \mu))$ is $L^\infty(K, \mu)$, which is abelian.

What about if you take X={} singleton, then $C(X)$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^2$, but it's commutant is $M_2(\mathbb{C})$

@PKOA There’s no cyclic vector in that case.
